# How do I get my hudson project build to fail on second set of nosetests?

Tags: python, bash, hudson, functional-testing, nosetests

I'm relatively new to Hudson, so please forgive me if this is a "duh" question.

I have a project written in python (employing pylons and nosetests) that includes both a server component and a client component. I have function tests set up in both the server hierarchy, and the client hierarchy, to exercise both components. In my build script (a shell script launched from the hudson project configuration page), I run two different nosetests, serially, like so:

```
# Python tests for server
find $WORKSPACE/server/src/project/tests -iname "*test_*.py" | xargs $NOSETESTS --with-coverage --cover-package=project --cover-html --cover-erase --with-pylons="$PYLONS_INI"
echo "SERVER TEST EXIT STATUS: $?"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    test_status=$test_status+$?
    export TEST_STATUS=$test_status
    exit $?
fi
```

(Then, after starting up the server)

```
# Python tests for client
find $WORKSPACE/server/src/project/tests -iname "*test_*.py" | xargs $NOSETESTS --with-coverage --cover-package=projectclient --cover-html --cover-erase --with-pylons="$PYLONS_INI"
echo "CLIENT TEST EXIT STATUS: $?"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    test_status=$test_status+$?
    export TEST_STATUS=$test_status
    exit $?
fi
```

Then I shut the server down.

The first set of tests (the server tests) always work. If a test fails, the build reports a failure, and the ball turns red. The second set (the client tests), however, never work. If a test fails, the STDOUT reports the failure, and the script shows an exit status of 123, but the build never fails.

I've tried adding

```
maven.test.failure.ignore=false
```

to my hudson configuration, based on some other questions I've seen here on stackoverflow, but it doesn't seem to have made a difference. I've tried forcing the script to terminate with an artificial exit value to see if it was even paying attention to the exit value, and that didn't change things. I've also tried moving the client tests above the server tests, to see if there were some reason why hudson only allowed for one set of nosetests, but that didn't seem to change things either.

If anyone has any idea what I might be doing wrong, I'd sure appreciate the help. If you need more information, just let me know.

Thanks!

============================

**UPDATE:**

I was able to get the second set of tests working like so:

```
find $WORKSPACE/client/python/src/tests -iname "*test_*.py" | xargs $NOSETESTS --with-coverage --cover-package=projectclient --cover-html --cover-erase --with-pylons="$PYLONS_INI"
client_test_status=$?
if [ $client_test_status -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Client Test Status = $client_test_status"
    exit $client_test_status
fi
```

However, I did not have to make this change to the SERVER tests. Only the client ones. The server tests still work, and still look like this:

```
find $WORKSPACE/server/src/project/tests -iname "*test_*.py" | xargs $NOSETESTS --with-coverage --cover-package=project --cover-html --cover-erase --with-pylons="$PYLONS_INI"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    exit $?
fi
```

One hypothesis floating around here, is that there might be an issue with the PIPE swallowing $?, but that doesn't explain why the server tests succeed (at failing), but the client tests do not (unless the $? is captured).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at your exit command makes me wonder why your build breaks when the server test fail. It might be connected with the fact that your server doesn't start when your build fails. In fact you are checking the **exit status of echo** and not of the exit status of your test suite. Capture your exit status first `my_exit = $?` and then always use `$my_exit` instead of `$?`.

Comment: Thats a great point. I'll give that a shot and get back to you.

Comment: @Peter - Peter, this was precisely the problem. But I'm really confused as to why. I put the $? off into a temp var and tested the temp var, and that failed the build as expected. Is it because "-ne" is resetting the $? ? But if that's the case, then I'm perplexed as to why this same problem doesn't exist for the server tests.

Comment: To clarify the above comment - I removed all the echoes, but the script was still exiting with a 0, until I stored the $? off into a temp var.

Comment: export sets its own exit code and guess what. Since the export worked the exit code is 0. -- BTW, why do you export a variable that you don't have access to, after you exit the script?

Comment: @Peter - the idea there, was to try to pass it back to HUDSON, so I could echo it from the little scripting interface, after the shell script exited. I've stripped all that nonsense out now. So, I just test for the exit code from the nosetests, using a temp var. But the question still remains: why don't I need to do the same on the server tests? So, while this is a "fix", it's raised more questions than answered :) I'll post an update to the original question text, to show you what I have now...

Comment: @GREG - AFAIK, the export will not work, otherwise you would have access to the variables from another build step and that doesn't work (at least under Windows). -- regarding the server tests, are you sure that your scripts reaches the if? May be the server test kills your whole script.